# How to use Bitcoin Wallet with MtGox?

Tags: wallet, mtgox, buy-bitcoins

I downloaded the Bitcoin Wallet from bitcoin.org; it's on my PC with a $0 balance. I want to purchase some bitcoins with dollars on MtGox, but how do I make it such that my purchase shows up in my wallet?

I have an account on MtGox, but I don't see anything under Funding Options where I can link my wallet with the MtGox transaction, then again, I've never purchased Bitcoins so maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to buy bitcoins on MtGox using another currency. These bitcoins will show up on your MtGox account.

You can then withdraw these bitcoins from your MtGox account to your own wallet. You can find this under `Funding options > Withdraw funds > Bitcoin`. Enter the address your wallet gives you and MtGox will send your coins to that address so that they show up in your wallet.

Comment: So in my Wallet there's a `Receive Coins` tab with a default address; I use that address in MtGox to withdraw into my wallet?

Comment: Yes, that's the way it works. Compare the address with your bank account number that you have to enter when you want to withdraw other currencies from MtGox or similar trading sites.

Comment: I see, and if I want to deposit bitcoins from my wallet into my MtGox account, I use the random address MtGox provides under the `Add Funds` tab?

Comment: Yes. But don't save the address, it will probably change over time so only use it immediately after you got it from MtGox.

Answer (score -2):

I live in the uk and am trying to purchase bitcoins from mt.gox. I dont know what option to use for this, it says there is a bank transfer option and OKPAY option(which seem to be the only available options for citezens). |Can anyone help???

Thanks

Comment: Please ask your own question.